# SwiftUI Animation bug?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm having this odd issue with macOS Montery 3 & Xcode 13 Beta 3, where I get this error with `List`'s and animations:

```
[General] Row index 0 out of row range (numberOfRows: 0) for <SwiftUIListCoreOutlineView: 0x133885000>
```

Its kinda hard to explain, but heres a simple reproduction:

### Minimal Reproducible Example

1. Create a new SwiftUI macOS application
2. Paste this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = ["Item"]
    
    @ViewBuilder var mainView: some View {
        if items.isEmpty {
            Text("Im empty")
        }
        else {
            List(items, id: \.self) {s in
                Text(s)
            }
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            mainView
                .toolbar {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            items.removeAll()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "minus")
                    }
                }
            Text("Second")
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run the app, and try resizing the sidebar. (You **should** be able to)
4. Then press the minus button on the toolbar. This **simply removes all the items**.
5. Then, the resizing of the sidebar should be broken. You might also get a bunch of errors in the console.

Is anybody able to reproduce this issue, and is it a bug in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the same behavior. The code works well if I remove the "withAnimation". Or put "items.removeAll()" outside the  "withAnimation"

Comment: Yeah. I think i'll just remove the animation